# У какого типа данных больше возможных значений: float или int?

Tags: типы-данных, типы, числа-с-плавающей-точкой

При использовании одинакового количества памяти какой числовой тип данных будет иметь большее количество доступных значений: целое или вещественное?

Comment: Количество возможных значений одинаковое, но числовой диапазон разный.

Comment: +0 и -0 считаем за одно значение, или за два?

Comment: При одинаковом количестве битов у целого ЛЮБОЕ сочетание битов означает осмысленное и уникальное значение, а вот у вещественного...

Comment: Числа с плавающей точкой хранятся в формате, где первый бит это знак, второй это экспотента 10^n и оставшияся биты несут ответственность за значение. Поэтому сложно сказать, во первых это зависит от того какие размеры ваш компилятор выделяет для каждых сегментов, float имеет большее кол-во значений так как для каждого числа экспотенты могут быть разные значения, но так же float не настолько точен.

Answer (score 1):

Допустим, есть раздел памяти в `8n`бит. Тогда максимальное количество уникальных значений равно 2 в степени `8n`. Во всех языках, из тех, что я знаю, разная комбинации битов приводит к разным значениям чисел: как для целого, так и для вещественного (с плавающей точкой) числа. Поэтому ответ: одинаково. Но в теории могут быть языки, где для float нет различия между +0 и -0, или между плюс бесконечностью, и минус бесконечностью.

Здесь имелись в виду числа, реализация которых встроенна в язык (обычно это int, long, float, double). В теории вы можете создать свою реализацию числа, где будут существовать две разных комбинации битов, приводящих к одинаковому значению числа.